# Adicionar mais de um botão de comprar no woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Eu uso um plugin para criar as paginas do produto do woocommerce, porque acho a página de venda padrão do produto muito simples,então eu adicionei alguns botões em lugares estratégicos para induzir o cliente a clicar nele.

O problema é que não sei como faço para que esse botão leve o cliente para o check-out, o máximo que consegui foi colocar um `#` e levar o cliente novamente ao topo da página.

Só que isso é um problema porque ele pode desistir e não clicar mais no botão comprar entende.

O que eu preciso é adicionar mais botões na pagina de vendas do produto e fazer com que ao clicar nele o cliente seja redirecionado para pagina de pagamento.

Comment: Cara, seria legal você disponibilizar o código de como você fez isso, só assim os usuários poderão o ajudar a  descobrir o motivo do erro e/ou corrigir o problema.

Comment: Salve meu camarada, na verdade não tem erro, talvez eu não tenha explicado direito. O que eu quero fazer é colocar mais botões de comprar na pagina do produto.

Por exemplo, eu faço a Land page e em alguns pontos eu vou colocar botões para a ação de comprar.

Comment: Entendi, a principal intencao do SO eh ajuda quando voce tem um problema, mas para isso primeiro voce tem que ter tentado fazer algo. Nao existe nenhuma intencao da comunidade de fazer as coisas por voce caso voce mesmo nao se esforce para isso em primeiro lugar. Mexa um pouco no seu codigo, tente fazer algo, entao volte com as duvidas, tenho certeza que muitas pessoas estarao sempre a disposicao para ajudar, mas nao para fazer por voce. ; )

Comment: Amigão não tô pedido pra ninguém fazer nada pra mim não, eu já procurei   e não encontrei nada parecido, perguntei pois talvez alguém aqui já tenha passado pela mesma situação e podia me dar uma força, mais obrigado pela resposta.